# Send Message From iframe to parent but differennt machine

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page on machine C with 2 iframes. One iframe shows http://A/foo.htm, the other shows http://B/foo.htm.  In order to make interaction, I use postMessage() to send messages from A to B via C, or from B to A via C.  But I cannot postMessage() from foo.htm in A to main page on C.

```
window.parent.postMessage("blabla","http://C/");
```

I execute this command in foo.htm in A and got an error:Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://C/') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://127.0.0.1').

I also write this code in my main page in machine C:

```
function CallByChild(){
        alert("Received command from child iFrame!");
    }
```

And write this code in foo.htm in A:

```
window.parent.CallByChild();
```

I also got an error:Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://A" from accessing a cross-origin frame.  Could someone teach me a way to solve it?

Sorry that English isn't my mother language.

Comment: It is CORS. All browsers prevent one page open inside it another page url. So you need to tell with your request that you kinda for sure want to make request to another page and another page also must have setup to accept request from some source that is in different domain. For testing you may disable that check on browser level but for production you need to do some setups on servers.

Comment: Oh and before actual GET or POST request CORS sent so called pre-flight OPTION request, which basically check that required endpoint exists and allow to do CORS request to it. Setup is highly depend on your tools and environment.